# Sublime text 3, Zurb Foundation and Compass (SASS)

Tags: zurb-foundation, sublimetext3, compass-sass

I'm a SASS/SCSS newbie and right after starting my first Zurb Foundation project I found in Sublime Text 3 error in the console

```
which: no compass in (/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
[ERROR] compass not found. Make sure it exists in your PATH.
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

I'm unable to continue. I had read a lot about how to use compass, but any usable information for "dumbers" step by step ST3+Compass+Foundation.
Compass tutorial on zurb's site ends with the error above.

Thank You

Comment: Hi
Use a terminal instead of terminal inside sublime text.
Are you sure compass is installed. Try writting  "compass version" in a terminal

Third. Don't use compass. I have done tons of websites, first with LESS, then SCSS+Compass, and now I just use SCSS. Compass is nice, but you will have a slow compiler, because it only runs on Ruby. Get libSASS instead. It runs on node alone, and is 20+ faster to compile

Comment: compass as is is installed and is working. Problem is only inside SublimeText editor while saving file. Tried libSASS and it worked.

Comment: much of compass, are just mixins. So if you still want a lot of the functionality and help from compass, you could just download all the mixins, and import them in your SCSS.
On small SCSS files you won't see big performance improvements, when compiling. but as things grow, performance is way better

Comment: Whatever it is it's got to do with your PATH environment variable.Think of it as a global namespace. Is sublime referenced in your PATH? If it isn't it would not be given the right to execute processes normally handled by the CLI and thus returning a not found.

Comment: Furthermore i highly recommend getting away from sublime console and using nodeJS + gulp to not only compile your sass but establish a watcher, that way you can recompile on save easily.

Comment: I'm a linux user, so my paths are in .bashrc. I use them for Java and Android SDK but I don't know why I have problems with gems.